# iOS Xcode 5 EXEC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) App Startup ONLY ON ONE DEVICE

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova

I am building a mobile app using PhoneGap and I have send it to Beta using TestFlight. Everyone has been able to download and test the app except for one user out of roughly 10. He can install the app perfectly fine, but when he goes to launch it, it crashes immediately. The first time he tried he got into the app, but when gave permissions to a plugin it crashed.

He provided me with a crash log, which I've shortened to:

```
Incident Identifier: BE251DD5-6D68-4084-84F6-EC629B24F2CA 
CrashReporter Key: 7cccfe6ca4af8513c8cdb2fc1cacf253a416553b 
Hardware Model: iPhone6,1 
Process: Loaner [1549] 
Path: /var/mobile/Applications/5B7BB625-9A3D-4ACE-A8A0-74424577067C/Loaner.app/Loaner 
Identifier: com.cardeninteractive.loaner 
Version: 1.1d (1.1d) 
Code Type: ARM-64 (Native) 
Parent Process: launchd [1] 
Date/Time: 2014-05-27 11:54:57.681 -0400 
OS Version: iOS 7.1.1 (11D201) 
Report Version: 104 

Exception Type: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000185806198     Triggered by Thread: 0 Thread 0 Crashed: 

0 CoreFoundation 0x0000000185806198 0x185800000 + 24984 
1 Loaner 0x00000001000407b4 0x100020000 + 133044 
2 Loaner 0x000000010003ec64 0x100020000 + 126052 
3 Loaner 0x0000000100039174 0x100020000 + 102772 
4 Loaner 0x000000010003a25c 0x100020000 + 107100 
5 libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001923ebfd0 0x1923e8000 + 16336 
6 libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001923f3834 0x1923e8000 + 47156 
7 libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001923ebfd0 0x1923e8000 + 16336 
8 libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001923ef1d8 0x1923e8000 + 29144 
9 CoreFoundation 0x00000001858cac28 0x185800000 + 830504 
10 CoreFoundation 0x00000001858c8f68 0x185800000 + 823144 
11 CoreFoundation 0x0000000185809c1c 0x185800000 + 39964 
12 GraphicsServices 0x000000018b4f1c08 0x18b4e4000 + 56328 
13 UIKit 0x000000018893afd8 0x1888c0000 + 503768 
14 Loaner 0x0000000100035f68 0x100020000 + 89960 
15 libdyld.dylib 0x0000000192407a9c 0x192404000 + 15004
```

I have read a number of posts on SO and can't seem to gain any insight into this.

Both myself and this guy are using an iPhone 5S and the problem doesn't affect me at all, even if I download the build from TestFlight and not through the IDE.

Comment: Which plugin requested the permissions? I'd start there. The above log doesn't tell me much, unfortunately.

Comment: He mentioned that once the app asked him to allow access to his contacts it crashed. I asked him to re-open the app and it would get to the loading screen and crash. I asked him to uninstall and reinstall from TestFlight, which he did. Same problem, only this time it crashed right away again.

I sent the app through the Archive process again in case something got corrupted. This didn't work either.

Works perfectly fine on my iPhone 5S, my wife's iPhone 5, my brothers iPhone 4S, and a friends iPhone 4.

So the device range seems to work, just not his phone for some reason.

Comment: Did he grant access or deny it?

Comment: Might help to symbolicate the crash log (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html). This particular exception code doesn't mean much to me (but a google search seems to indicate it may be a problem with memory management). It would help to see what's on the console, since something there might be helpful. The only other thing I can think to try is to send several builds his way without a certain plugin and see which one is causing the crash (that way you could narrow down the problematic plugin).

Comment: Also: is your friend's device jailbroken? Also, what version of iOS are you running and what version is he running?